# Multiple EmberJS Apps on Same Page in Liferay CMS

Tags: ember.js

**Background**
It is technically possible to load multiple ember apps on a single HTML page. When you are using a CMS like Liferay for an enterprise such scenarios may be un-avoidable as you have independent portlets on same page.

**Question 1**
How routing is handled in such case? I mean which emberApp routes would be called when user would change the URL in address-bar if there are multiple apps in different portlets on same page?

**Question 2**
How do we allow browsers to intelligently invoke right EmberApp based on some matched pattern in URL. The 2 ember apps in this case address seperate user concerns so it makes sense to design them as seperate portlets rather than making a single App.

Comment: I think ember engines is what you are looking for. But that is still in RFC stage. https://github.com/tomdale/rfcs/blob/master/active/0000-engines.md https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/10

Comment: Thanks @blessenm , I am looking for a simpler option like may be deactivating/unloading an ember-app if URL does not have a specific sub-string and re-loading it if the URL sub-string is matched.